# How to parse a string in python

Tags: python, parsing

Without any 3rd party libraries (such as beautiful soup) what is the cleanest way to parse a string in PYTHON.

Given the text below I'd like the content of "uber_token" be parsed out ie. "123456789"

....

```
<form id="blah" action="/p-submi.html" method="post"><input type="hidden" id="" name="uber_token" value="123456789"/><div class="container-info">
```

....

Thanks!

Comment: do you need to tokenize all the elements and attributes or simply extract the `value="XXX"` part? If its just the latter, use a regex.

Comment: just need the value="xxx". But there are multiple instances of value="**" which may have a different associated name.

Comment: If the attributes and their ordering is consistent in every element you can use a regex for that, but why are you averse to using a library?

Comment: Note that if you need the names that accompany the values too, maybe update your question.

Comment: If each `<input type="hidden" id="" name="uber_token" value="123456789"/>` is one per line. Then you can just seatch for `name` and parse the two quotations after. If its equal to uber_token then find `value` and parse between the two quotations after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regular expression is the solution.

use `import re`

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '<form id="blah" action="/p-submi.html" method="post"><input type="hidden" id="" name="uber_token" value="123456789"/><div class="container-info"'
>>> regex=re.search(r'name="uber_token" value="([0-9]+)"',s)
>>> print regex.group(1)
123456789
```

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: This answer is for quick-and-dirty scripts, and may lack in robustness and efficiency. Suggestions here should probably not be used for code that survives more than a few hours.*

If you're unwilling to learn regex (and you should be willing to learn regex!), you can split on `value="`. Probably really inefficient, but simple is easier to debug.

```
values = []

with open('myfile.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        candidates = line.split('value="')
        for s in candidates[1:]: #the first token is not a value
            try: #test if value is a number
                val = int(s.split('"')[0]) 
            except:
                continue
            values.append(val)
```

---

If you're specifically looking at HTML or XML, Python has libraries for both.

- `HTMLParser`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html
- `ElementTree`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Then, for example, you can write code to search through the tree for a node with an attribute "name" that has value "uber_token", and get the "value" attribute from it.

Very dumb Python 2 example that doesn't require learning too much about `ElementTree`s (may need simple corrections):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('myfile.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

values = []

for element in root:
    if element.attrib['name'] == 'uber_token':
        values.append(element.attrib['value'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Python comes with it's own xml parsing module : https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/xml.html?highlight=xml#xml so you don't have to use any third party parsing lib. If you're unwilling or not allowed to use that..... you can always drop to regex , but i'd stay clear of that when it comes to parsing XML